# Sillcock Replacement

Tags: plumbing, soldering

I have a sillcock that I want to replace though I can not tell if it is threaded on or soldered. I have tried turning it but it will not budge. If it is soldered, will it be hard to un-solder and re-solder the new one on?
[image]

**UPDATE (question):**
How can I find out what length I need to by for my sillcock?

Comment: It looks s if those two pipes are already separated.

Comment: It is hard to tell in the picture but at the end of the sillcock the pipe widens. So that may be why it looks like they are not connected.

Comment: it looks as though the knurled section is threaded on

Comment: @jsotola  I think the knurled section is part of the threads and used to tighten the threads into a female threaded end but the water pipe was fitted inside.

Comment: where is the sillcock in relation to that picture?

Comment: The sillcock is the pipe that goes into the insulation.

Comment: @JACK Can you check if my understanding is correct: the knurled part is soldered onto the pipe, and then is the sillcock threaded on to the knurled part? Or is it soldered onto the knurled part? If it is soldered, how did they do that?

Comment: I think the knurled, threaded piece is part of the sillcock. All sillcocks I have worked with have a threaded end. It looks like the water pipe was inserted into the sillcock and soldered instead of soldering a female threaded adapter to the end of the water pipe and then just screwing the sillcock into the adapter.  The soldering would have been done before the insulation was added. You'd need to protect the wiring if you're going to solder up there with some heat shields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sillcock appears to be soldered on to the water pipe. There should have been a female adapter soldered on to the water pipe and then the sillcock would just screw onto the water pipe. You've got a few options here:

1) Cut the water pipe, solder a female adapter on the water pipe and screw in a new sillcock.

2) Cut the water pipe and get a SharkBite sillcock and shove it onto the water pipe.

3)Unsolder the existing sillcock, clean up the water pipe and solder a new sillcock onto the water pipe.

I would be doing the first option as it makes future replacements easier.